# How to use a Backbone view in bootstrap modal for login and perform task after login?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, bootstrap-modal

I have a backbone view call LogOnView. In my LogOnView A user can login using username and password. There exist all type of server and client side validation. I want to use this view in a bootstrap modal when a user click a button in another view. I can add all the content LogOnView into bootstrap modal-body like this

```
$('.modal-body').html(new LogOnView().el);
```

N.B. I am enabling the Bootstrap modal dynamically that means from a view (using javascript).

```
$('#LogOnPopUp').modal('toggle');
```

By this content of LogOnView is successfully added to Boostrap modal. And also login and validation is ok as it ok in LogOnView. But I need to find a way to do another work when user Login successfully. That means when an user successfully login the modal popup will close and another task will need to done in this view.

So what can I do in this aspect? Any advice will be appreciable.

N.B: (summary/similar criteria )
It's all the same as facebook like. When anyone like a content of other website using facebook account. A user click in like button then a modal popup is opened and after logged in there his like is confirmed.

I want to do something like this using my LogOnView into bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you want to execute an action once some work has been done (i.e. logging on, in your case), you can handle "doing things after" using jQuery Deferreds and promises: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

I've written 2 posts on the subject, if this is the route you want to use:

- http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/
- http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/02/rendering-a-view-after-multiple-async-functions-return-using-promises/

Comment: Thanks @David. I have seen your posts. I have used such callback and deferred object in other aspects. I am using node.js so that I am well known about callback function and I have used deferred object in case of loading template of all view. But I think thats for a function or a specific task. But I was talking about a total views. I am calling a view from another view and load content into the modal-body. I need to go back to first view when I have called the second view(LogOnView) after login so that I can perform or close modal.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to manage a modal window? Take a look at http://www.backbonerails.com/screencasts/building-dialogs-with-custom-regions